# No yaml syntax for ansible local_action?

Tags: ansible

I have a working local_action task which I like to write in yaml syntax. But it seems that this is either not possible or tricky. There are some mentions in the net that people have tried to do so. I have not found a proof that it is not possible...

This is the working code (inline):

```
- name: create opt file
  local_action:  template  src=templates/module-deployment.opt.j2  dest=/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}/module-deployment.opt
```

This is my closest version to structure the code  (but not yaml syntax):

```
- name: create opt file
  local_action:  template
    src=templates/module-deployment.opt.j2   
    dest=/tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}/module-deployment.opt
```

This is what I would have expected but this is *not* working:

```
  - name: create opt file
    local_action:  
    template: 
       src: templates/module-deployment.opt.j2   
       dest: tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}/module-deployment.opt
```

The error message is not too helpful.

```
The offending line appears to be:
- name: create opt file for contentPump
  ^ here
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to archive this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This is what I would have expected but this is *not* working [ ]

You can always rely on the [documentation](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) instead of your own expectations:

```
- name: create opt file 
  local_action:
    module: template
    src: templates/module-deployment.opt.j2
    dest: tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}/module-deployment.opt
```